# How to create a matching regex pattern for "greater than 10-000-000 and lower than 150-000-000"?

Tags: regex

I'm trying to make

> 09-546-943

fail in the below regex pattern.

> ​^[0-9]{2,3}[- ]{0,1}[0-9]{3}[- ]{0,1}[0-9]{3}$

Passing criteria is
greater than 10-000-000 or 010-000-000 and
less than 150-000-000

The tried example "09-546-943" passes. This should be a fail.
Any idea how to create a regex that makes this example a fail instead of a pass?

Comment: does "greater than" means the whole string (without dashes) as a number is greater than, or each of the string part as a number is greater than?

Comment: yes. like a number validation between ten million and one hundred and fifty million.

Answer (score 4):

You may use

```
^(?:(?:0?[1-9][0-9]|1[0-4][0-9])-[0-9]{3}-[0-9]{3}|150-000-000)$
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/kPA1X3/2/).

The pattern is partially generated with [this online number range regex generator](http://gamon.webfactional.com/regexnumericrangegenerator/), I set the min number to `10` and max to `150`, then merged the branches that match `1-8` and `9` (the tool does a bad job here), added `0?` to the two digit numbers to match an optional leading `0` and `-[0-9]{3}-[0-9]{3}` for `10-149` part and `-000-000` for `150`.

See the [regex graph](https://jex.im/regulex/#!flags=&re=%5E(%3F%3A(%3F%3A0%3F%5B1-9%5D%5B0-9%5D%7C1%5B0-4%5D%5B0-9%5D)-%5B0-9%5D%7B3%7D-%5B0-9%5D%7B3%7D%7C150-000-000)%24):

[image]

**Details**

- `^` - start of string
- `(?:` - start of a container non-capturing group making the anchors apply to both alternatives:

  - `(?:0?[1-9][0-9]|1[0-4][0-9])` - an optional `0` and then a number from 10 to 99 or `1` followed with a digit from 0 to 4 and then any digit (100 to 149)
  - `-[0-9]{3}-[0-9]{3}` - a hyphen and three digits repeated twice (=`(?:-[0-9]{3}){2}`)
- `|` - or

  - `150-000-000` - a `150-000-000` value
- `)` - end of the non-capturing group
- `$` - end of string.

Comment: Minor update ... ^(?:(?:0?[1-9][0-9]|1[0-4][0-9])(-[0-9]{3}){2}|150-000-000)$

Comment: @Hemang  I know, I added that option in my explanation. However, there are environments that flag the use of nested quantifiers, and this pattern is not that long, so repeating it just twice seems to be more readable for me.

Answer (score 0):

This expression or maybe a slightly modified version of which might work:

```
^[1][0-4][0-9]-[0-9]{3}-[0-9]{3}$|^[1][0]-[0-9]{3}-[0-9]{2}[1-9]$
```

It would also fail `10-000-000` and `150-000-000`.

In this [demo](https://regex101.com/r/rNR28v/1/), the expression is explained, if you might be interested.

Comment: Thank you for the demo. It fails for 010-000-001 but passes 10-000-001. Any idea?

Answer (score 0):

This pattern:

```
((0?[1-9])|(1[0-4]))[0-9]-[0-9]{3}-[0-9]{3}
```

matches the range from  `(0)10-000-000` to `149-999-999` inclusive. To keep the regex simple, you may need to handle the extremes (`(0)10-000-000` and `150-000-000`) separately - depending on your need of them to be included or excluded.

Test [**here**](https://regex101.com/r/Rqe4tG/1).

This regex:

```
((0?[1-9])|(1[0-4]))[0-9][- ]?[0-9]{3}[- ]?[0-9]{3}
```

accepts  (space) or nothing instead of `-`.

Test [**here**](https://regex101.com/r/Rqe4tG/2).